# Why won't pandas excel writer write to my file path?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to output an .xlsx file with pd.ExcelWriter as shown below:

```
writer_t = pd.ExcelWriter('C:/Users/bbecker021/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/Project_Catalog_Template_IDs.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')`
```

I then append to the file with:

```
data_requirements_DF.to_excel(writer_t, sheet_name=repo_list[element])
```

And print out the dataframe being added:

```
print("---", repo_list[element], "data_requirements---\n", data_requirements_DF)
```

But when I check the folder path I specify above, there is no file...any help as to check what might be happening?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].